# Trigger to enter deleted entries to a new table - SQL plus

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which will enter values into a table terminated_employees when we delete values from the nm_employees table. I have written the trigger but it does not work. Is my trigger format right? Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE nm_departments(
dept2 varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT empPK PRIMARY KEY (dept2)
);

CREATE TABLE nm_employees(
name varchar(20),
dept varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT departments FOREIGN KEY (dept) REFERENCES nm_departments (dept2)ON DELETE         CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE terminated_employees(
te_name varchar(20),
te_dept varchar(20)
);


CREATE TRIGGER term_employee AFTER DELETE ON nm_employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO terminated_employees (NEW.te_name, NEW.te_dept) VALUES  (OLD.name,OLD.dept)
END;
```

Comment: "but it does not seem to work." - that is not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be specifying the `NEW.` on the column names of your `INSERT` statement. These are the columns in the `terminated_employees` table, NOT the new values. i.e.

```
INSERT INTO terminated_employees (te_name, te_dept)
VALUES  (OLD.name,OLD.dept)
```

You can use `show errors` (or `show err`) in SQL*Plus to see the exact error.

You have a number of problems:

- Wrong table name on create trigger (missing the `s`)
- Missing `;` after instert statement
- The `OLD.` need to have `:` prefix. i.e. `:OLD.name`

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER term_employee AFTER DELETE ON nm_employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO terminated_employees (te_name,te_dept) VALUES  (OLD.name,OLD.dept)
END;

Comment: @Nidhin_toms You should include the error messages in your post. It'll help you get an accurate answer faster. I just guessed what the problem might be

Comment: it says that the trigger has not been compiled properly.